# SegmentedControl in TableViewCell - Proper way to reuse cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Trying to get a better grasp of how an UITableViews works, so I provided a background question I'm not sure about, which leads into my actual question below

1) When a cell is first created, you include the

```
if (!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

block to init the cell. After that, if you are reusing a cell, the if-statement will be skipped and you will just use the previous cell you setup before for the new cell you are now creating (be the deque method). Is that correct?

2) Using Storyboard, I have a segmented control created in a prototype cell for two indices: "Attending" and "Not Attending", so every new cell creates a new segmented control. No index should be selected upon creation of a cell, however I was having trouble as an index would be selected when I added a new row/cell to the table.

Let's take this scenario: I create my first cell, "Attending" and "Not Attending" are both not selected as expected. Say now I select one of the indices, and now add a new row/cell to my table. The question I have is when I setup breakpoints and I'm looking at the creation of a new cell, namely this step below

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
...

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

And I look at my selectedIndex in the debugger, it stores the same selectedIndex value as the cell I just modified (ie. "Attending" or "Not Attending," whatever I selected before represented by 0 or 1). I guess this makes sense because I am dequeue-ing a reusablecell, so I guess the tags and such point to the previous cell? I was able to solve this problem of resetting the new cell to have no index selected at creation by doing the following:

Note, the default selectedIndex for new event object/cell, labeled here as"announcements," is 2):

```
   //set correct index
    if ([[self.announcements objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] selectedIndex] == 2){
        [attendingSegmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:UISegmentedControlNoSegment];
    }
    else {
        attendingSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = [[self.announcements objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] selectedIndex];
    }
```

So now when I create a new cell, even though the SegmentedControl selectedIndex is either 0 or 1 (after I already selected in a previous cell), the initial selectedIndex for the **object** is 2. Hence I'm forcing the SegmentedContorl's selectedIndex to change to nothing being selected. Is this the right approach here? Been reading up on cell dequeing questions and this was the best solution I came up with myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) It's correct but if you use a storyboard with prototype cells or if your [register](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:) a custom cell class manually for `CellIdentifier` then you can just call

```
[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

and it will always return a correct cell (see the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:))

2) You can do it that way but for simplicity you could even use -1 (or `UISegmentedControlNoSegment`) instead of 2 for the the selectedIndex of a new cell. That way you can avoid your `if (selectedIndex == 2)` and if someday you wan to add a third segment to your segmented control then it won't break there.

If you would have more properties to reset before reuse a cell then I'd advise you to subclass `UITableViewCell` and do the reset work in the [prepareForReuse](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewCell/prepareForReuse) method.